# PostgreSQL cannot work when opens SSL on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql-10, ssl

I am not sure this topic will fit here but I don't know ask it where.

I am trying to open the SSL of PostgreSQL 10.16 on Windows10.

I read a lot of documents about creating an SSL certificate to PostgreSQL but documents spend on Windows 10 are rare and don't detail.

These are the steps which I did:

**Step 1**, I download the OpenSSL version of Windows from

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

and install it with the path C:\OpenSSL-Win64, setting system variable.

**Step 2**, I use cmd run as an admin to create server key with command line:

```
genrsa -out server.key 4096
```

, setting appropriate permission and owner on the private key file (here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463654)

```
icacls server.key /reset

icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"
```

and I got a response from cmd.exe in this command-line

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>icacls server.key /reset
processed file:  server.key
Successfully processed 1 file; Failed processing 0 files

C:\WINDOWS\system32>icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"
processed file:  server.key
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

continue to create the server certificate:

```
req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key server.key -out server.crt
```

**Step 3**, since I am self-signing, I use the server certificate as the trusted root certificate, so I have 3 files: server.key, server.crt, and root.crt (this is a copy of server crt)

I move these three files to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data

**Step 4**, I am setting postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
ssl=on
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

and add command-line to the end of pg_hba.conf:

```
# IPv4 remote connections for authenticated users
hostssl   all     postgres             0.0.0.0/0            md5 clientcert=1
```

**Finally**, I get an error as below when I restart my PostgreSQL

```
The PostgreSQL -x64-10 -PostgreSQL Server 10 service on the Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
```

and in my log of PostgreSQL:

```
2021-03-28 16:35:44.735 +07 [7624] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-28 16:34:51 +07

2021-03-28 16:35:45.099 +07 [7044] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

2021-03-28 17:39:37.827 +07 [7044] LOG:  received fast shutdown request

2021-03-28 17:39:37.834 +07 [7044] LOG:  aborting any active transactions

2021-03-28 17:39:37.839 +07 [7044] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 7972) exited with exit code 1

2021-03-28 17:39:37.843 +07 [7880] LOG:  shutting down

2021-03-28 17:39:37.877 +07 [7044] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I suspect PostgreSQL did not read the 3 files that I put in its data directory.

I have referenced these documents

https://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959324/chmod-og-rwx-server-key-in-windows/51463654#51463654

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ssl-tcp.html

I have been messing with it for many days and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: are you sure that your version has ´With SSL support compiled in` else compile it yoirself

Comment: @nbk I am not sure. How to know my version is SSL support compiled?

Comment: see the chapter 16 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/installation.html  i don't know how to che4ck postgres it the support is inclued, hopefully another user can tell you that, but i seems to me as you must complie it your self

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, maybe I was too in a hurry and forgot this.